# Stored Procedure Update Single row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in SQL Server that will essentially update a table given a condition.

Let's say I have a table with **Orders**

| Order ID | Product ID | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | BEA10 | 2 |
| 1000 | RAN25 | 5 |
| 1001 | RAN50 | 3 |
| 1001 | RAN25 | 1 |
| 1001 | RAN60 | 4 |
| 1002 | BEA10 | 1 |

A table we want to insert into let's call this **InsertOrder** Table

| ID | Code | Order ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC1 | NULL |
| 2 | ABC2 | NULL |
| 3 | ABC3 | NULL |
| 4 | ABC4 | NULL |
| 5 | ABC5 | NULL |
| 6 | ABC6 | NULL |

What I am trying to do is look through the **Orders** table where the Product ID = 'BEA10' and update a single row in the **InsertOrder** table and set it to the Order ID where we found the Product ID of 'BEA10' as long as that Order ID in the InsertOrder info table is NULL

I guess that would mean that if we run the stored proc again it should ignore already inserted Order ID's.

I am fairly new to SQL so I tried to build up some form of code but it seems way off

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrder] 
    
AS

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @ORDERS_PRODUCTID nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @ORDERS_ORDERID int;

SELECT @ORDERS_PRODUCTID = ProductID from ORDERS
SELECT @ORDERS_ORDERID = OrderID from ORDERS

IF(@ORDERS_PRODUCTID = 'BEA10' and @ORDERS_ORDERID not in (SELECT OrderID from InsertOrder)) 

BEGIN
    

    
    UPDATE InsertOrder SET OrderID = @ORDERS_ORDERID where OrderID is null
    
END
GO
```

Comment: FYI, your `SET NOCOUNT` statement should be at the *start* of the procedure, not the middle.

Comment: Does your InsertOrder table auto-increment ABC1, ABC2, etc.?

Comment: @ProdigalTechie Sorry there is actually a column called Id which auto increments 1,2,3,4 the Code column were manually inserted and are all unique. Will update table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it works

```
DECLARE @ORDERS_PRODUCTID nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @ORDERS_ORDERID int;

SET @ORDERS_ORDERID = (SELECT OrderID 
                        FROM ORDERS O 
                        WHERE ProductID='BEA10' 
                            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM InsertOrder WHERE OrderID=O.OrderID));

UPDATE InsertOrder 
SET OrderID = @ORDERS_ORDERID 
WHERE Code=(SELECT TOP 1 Code FROM InsertOrder WHERE OrderID is null);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).